# Permeability determination (estimation) from geometry in undirectional air flow through porous media

Tags: fluid-dynamics, porous-media

So I have to model a porous wind barrier that would stop the majority of dust from entering but also allows air to go in. I have decided to start with a 1D flow assumption with unidirectional porosity. From some literature search, I got the required porosity to be around 45%. I am stuck with an estimate of the permeability. I am simulating it numerically so I don't have experimental data. I have taken a material that won't deform significantly, So based on geometry (I have taken the pores to be rectangular slits of 0.3mm thickness), How can I get an estimate of the specific permeability? Also, will compressibility effects play a role at naturally occurring wind velocities?

Comment: Look up the viscosity of air in any handbook, like Marks Mechanical Engineers' Handbook or Perry's Chemical Engineers handbook, or Google "viscosity of air".  The need to include compressibility of air depends on the superficial velocity and thickness.  Assume it is incompressible, and accept answer if the pressure changes by less than 10%; otherwise, include compressibility.

Comment: Thanks for the info, can you give some references to calculate permeability based on geometry of pores?

Comment: Your are assuming pores featuring viscous flow between parallel plates.  See Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena and Groundwater by Freeze and Cherry.   This is the parallel plate version of Poiseuille flow in a tube.  In any event you are going to have to measure the permeability.